# Why is wrong data types when using option of inferSchema as true in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading a USA_Housing.csv file which the columns are 
(Avg Area Income, Avg Area House Age, Avg Area Number of Rooms, Avg Area Number of Bedrooms, Area Population, Price, Address)
all columns are numerical value except Address 
when reading data by this:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val data = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").format("csv").load("USA_Housing.csv")
data.printSchema()`

**output of printSchema is:**

```
 |-- Avg Area Income: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Avg Area House Age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Avg Area Number of Rooms: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Avg Area Number of Bedrooms: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Area Population: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Address: string (nullable = true)
```

as **the avg area income and area house age** are both **string** but they are actual **double** in csv file.

when i open data by ATOM it's shown as:

```
Avg Area Income,Avg Area House Age,Avg Area Number of Rooms,Avg Area Number of Bedrooms,Area Population,Price,Address
79545.45857431678,5.682861321615587,7.009188142792237,4.09,23086.800502686456,1059033.5578701235,"208 Michael Ferry Apt. 674
Laurabury, NE 37010-5101"
79248.64245482568,6.0028998082752425,6.730821019094919,3.09,40173.07217364482,1505890.91484695,"188 Johnson Views Suite 079
Lake Kathleen, CA 48958"
```

Comment: Please provide your sample file

Comment: @ChandanRay I added 2 lines of data but in csv file the whole address content is defined for its cell when opening by excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting multiLine to true should work.

```
val data = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("multiLine", "true").format("csv").load("USA_Housing.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The csv (from kaggle) seems mal formated, there is a line-break in the adress column. So the first column is actually parsed as:

```
+------------------+
|               _c0|
+------------------+
| 79545.45857431678|
|         Laurabury|
| 79248.64245482568|
|     Lake Kathleen|
|61287.067178656784|
|        Danieltown|
| 63345.24004622798|
|     FPO AP 44820"|
|59982.197225708034|
|     FPO AE 09386"|
```

Therefore spark takes this as string

Comment: It's as you mentioned but how can solve this issue I tried to add `option("sep",",")` to sep for each , data but it's failed